# Why is fetch_assoc returning false?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, email, password, code FROM temp_users WHERE code = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $code);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
//if SELECT statement returns 1, grab data.
if ($stmt->num_rows === 1) {
    echo "Got Row";

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    var_dump($result);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $username = $row['username'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $password = $row['password'];
    }
```

This is really weird, the query must be going through because the script is echoing "Got Row", and I have no errors up to that point. But when I try to use $result->fetch_assoc() I get an error,and $result is spitting out false, so why is that? Please excuse how dumb this question may seem, I'm still learning how to use mysqli. :)

Comment: The $code variable is defined above the posted code. So that isn't the issue.

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: What's your PHP version?  `get_result()` is only available with the MySQLND driver (in later PHP versions).  If you don't have that driver, you have to use the old `bind_result()` and `fetch()` method with MySQLi.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php  I think it ships with 5.3 but isn't default, and is the default MySQL driver in 5.4+

Comment: CMate, Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

Your question is neither dumb nor weird. You are simply confused by `store_result()` and `get_result()`.

Both of these functions fetch the whole record set from the database. Once the data is fetched you can't fetch it again. Therefore, **you can't use both of these functions at the same time!**

We can fix your code in two ways.

With `store_result()`:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, email, password, code FROM temp_users WHERE code = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $code);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
//if SELECT statement returns 1, grab data.
if ($stmt->num_rows === 1) {
    echo "Got Row";

    $stmt->bind_result($username, $email, $password);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        // use the data here
        var_dump($username);
    }
}
```

with `get_result()`:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, email, password, code FROM temp_users WHERE code = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $code);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
//if SELECT statement returns 1, grab data.
if ($result->num_rows === 1) { // <--- !!! We are using the result object here
    echo "Got Row";

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $username = $row['username'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $password = $row['password'];
    }
}
```